# It is possible to have sphinx MyST rendering mermaid

Tags: python-sphinx, mermaid, myst

It is possible to make work mermaid inside `\.md` file with MyST md driver ?

For now the only way I found is

```
$ tail conf.py
extensions = [ 'recommonmark', 'sphinxcontrib.mermaid']
from recommonmark.transform import AutoStructify
def setup(app):
    app.add_transform(AutoStructify)
$
```

The below is rendered with `recommonmark`:

````
```mermaid::

  graph LR
    a --> b
```
````

but not with `MyST-parser`

I have open this issue in MyST: https://github.com/executablebooks/MyST-Parser/issues/366

Note: `recommonmark` does not render correctly tables that's why I try to use `MyST-parser`

Comment: Notice that recommonmark is deprecated in favor of myst-parser https://github.com/readthedocs/recommonmark/issues/221

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mermaid` is prefectly integrated to `MyST-parser`.

You only need to call it like that with `{mermaid}`:

````
```{mermaid}
graph LR
  a --> b
```
````

No need to define in `conf.py` a `def setup(app):` only:

```
extensions = ['myst_parser', 'sphinxcontrib.mermaid']
```

Comment: Why `{mermaid}` instead of the usual `mermaid`?

Comment: This what is recommended from official sphinxcontrib-mermaid README documentation (see https://github.com/mgaitan/sphinxcontrib-mermaid#markdown-support). This is also the standard recommended from myST-parser for using Sphinx directives (see https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/v0.13.5/using/syntax.html#extended-block-tokens)

Answer (score 2):

As of [myst-parser 0.19.2](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/develop/_changelog.html#id3) you can use the regular markdown syntax with `mermaid` instead of `{mermaid}`.

This way previews (e.g. on GitHub or in your editor) will also work properly.

The minimal `conf.py` change that is needed looks like this:

```py
extensions = ['myst_parser', 'sphinxcontrib.mermaid']
myst_fence_as_directive = ["mermaid"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tips:
Need to `pip install sphinxcontrib-mermaid`

from [myst-parser](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/v0.17.1/sphinx/intro.html)